# How to find the X- and Y- axis interecpt of a plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

Please consider this sample code:

```
a=2.3;b=5.3; % constants
n=1000;  % number of data blocks
data=a+(b-a)*rand(1,3500); % data points
count=0;
x=[1:.1:7]; % x-axis
bins=hist(data,x);
for i=length(x):-1:1
    count=count+bins(i);
    ccdf(i)=count/n;
end
semilogy(x,ccdf) % CCDF of data
```

My question is that if we could find and mark the Y-axis intercept.

Or X-axis intercept of this:

```
plot(x,ccdf) % find its x-axis interecpt
```

I can use the **Data Marker** option in Matlab Figure to mark the X & Y axis values but is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your intercept is just the first data points, this is very easy:

```
.
.
.
semilogy(x,ccdf) % CCDF of data
hold on
plot(x(1), ccdf(1), '*r')
```

Hmmm well actually I guess that depends on what you mean by intercept. Do you mean where it crosses y - zero and x = zero? So in that case there is no y intercept. And ccfd seems to be zero for the last 15 elements or so...

So why don't you use the data marker and post an image of which intercepts you wants exactly - especially since values for y == 0 won't show on a semilogy plot since they'd be at -infinity...

Comment: :That marks the Y-intercept but i also want to find the value of it.

Comment: @user2888999 well the value is `ccdf(1)`